# No instance for MyClass arising from a use of `throwError'

Tags: haskell, types, monads, monad-transformers

I have a problem with typing. I started to study Monad transformers with [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers). Then I little changed them example. Now, my code is:

```
data PwdError = PwdError String

type PwdErrorMonad = ErrorT PwdError IO

isValid :: String -> ErrorT String PwdErrorMonad Bool
isValid s
    | length s < 5 = throwError "password is short!"
    | otherwise = return True
```

Now, I have the error:

```
No instance for (Error PwdError) arising from a use of `throwError'
In the expression: throwError "password is short!"
In an equation for `isValid':
    isValid s
      | length s < 5 = throwError "password is too short!"
      | otherwise = return True
```

Could you help me to compile this program?

Comment: You need to have `instance Error PwdError where ...` somewhere in your code.  Look at the `Error` class' documentation to figure out what functions you need to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `PwdError` an instance of [the `Error` typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html#t:Error).

The following should be sufficient, though I haven't tried to compile it:

```
instance Error PwdError where
  strMsg = PwdError
```